# How can I reference a specific repository using Git?

Tags: git, github

In this repository (https://github.com/LaravelIO/laravel.io), you can have a look at `vagrant-chef` folder. When you click on it, you move to another repository.

How can I do that?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "submodule".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you mean Submodules, try this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Simple worked exmaple:

```
mkdir /SomeFolder
cd SomeFolder
git submodule add git@github.com:YourRepoHere.git
```

now the `YourRepo` will appear in the folder `SomeFolder`

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the reply. That's what I needed. Will pick this as the correct answer in few minutes.